# Sandbox Users not found via API

Tags: sandbox, instagram-api

Yesterday I could find a user via the API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search/?q=...&access_token=...
```

But now everything returns Meta-code-200 and empty data.

What happened?

Comment: I mean all users invited in sandbox

Comment: Your question is missing tags, such as the fact you're using some kind of web service. Also, add clarifications by editing your question itself, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is in sandbox mode then you can get information about only sandbox invited users.

If you app is in live mode then make sure public_content permission is Approved.

Please also check scope you are using. Make sure in scope you are sending public_content permission.